# Pardot general user

Tags: pardot, reply-mail-management

I can't find where in Pardot to define the "General user" email address. It has been setup to a certain email address, but need to change it.

I see that the "general user email address" is used in an email template, but it's not editable (and I don't know where can I change its email address).

[image: The general user email address is here but where do I change it?]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I didn't check the email template builder, which provides the way to choose which user will send it.

[image]

It was there all the time.

(Leave it in case other silly users like me find themselves in trouble...)